# SwiftUI LazyStack with ForEach and Array: strange behavior

Tags: arrays, foreach, swiftui, scrollview

If use LazyStack with ForEach for creating new array, final array became chaotic like [4,0,1,56]
Are there any solution to make normal array behavior ?

```
struct TestScrollBackView: View {
@State private var stored: Int = 0
@State private var current: [Int] = []
var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Store") {
                    // hard code is just for demo !!!
                    stored = current.sorted()[1] // 1st is out of screen by LazyVStack
                    print("!! stored \(stored)")
                }
                Button("Restore") {
                    proxy.scrollTo(stored, anchor: .top)
                    print("[x] restored \(stored)")
                }
            }
            Divider()
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<1000, id: \.self) { obj in
                        Text("Item: \(obj)")
                            .onAppear {
                                print(">> added \(obj)")
                                current.append(obj)
                            }
                            .onDisappear {
                                current.removeAll { $0 == obj }
                                print("<< removed \(obj)")
                            }.id(obj)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The question is: why are you storing an array based on the appearance of the element?

Comment: Agree with the above, but the views in a LazyVStack don't necessarily render in order. I found this out when trying to determine which views were actually on screen. ForEach is for view only. It is not for things like this.

Comment: The main idea for that is to determine only visible views, stored their id in the array, save the id of the first view - the second element in the array. Scroll several times and by clicking Restore button to move back to the saved view by using scrollTo method. That’s why I need not chaotic array, because each time I move to different views, not the second one :)